# When to use type() instead of isinstanceof() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From what I read googling, it seems that `isinstanceof()` is always better than `type()`.

What are some situations when using type() is better than isinstanceof() in python?

I am using python 3.7.

Comment: `type` is useful when you want to know *exactly* what type something has.  It's particularly useful when debugging something, or even just trying to understand it.  `isinstance` is good when you don't need to know the exact type, as long as it's derived from some particular type (e.g., you don't mind if it inherits the type or is the type itself).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Comment: @David, I'm a bit thick. When I read the answers, I get the impression that isinstanceof() is always better than type(). It doesn't answer my question directly.

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358473/6045800): *Type-checking with

`isinstance(obj, Base)`
allows for instances of subclasses and multiple possible bases:

`isinstance(obj, (Base1, Base2))`
whereas type-checking with

`type(obj) is Base`
only supports the type referenced.* It is not necessarily about better or worse, it is about what your use-case is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do two different things, you can't really compare them directly. What you've probably read is that you should prefer `isinstance` when *checking the type of an object at runtime*. But that isn't the only use-case for `type` (that *is* the use-case for `isinstance`, as its name implies).

What may not be obvious is that `type` is a *class*. You can think of "type" and "class" as synonymous. Indeed, it is the class of class objects, a *metaclass*. But it is a class just like `int`, `float`, `list`, `dict` etc. Or just like a use-defined class, `class Foo: pass`.

In its single argument form, it returns the *class of whatever object you pass in*. This is the form that can be used for type-checking. It is essentially equivalent to `some_object.__class__`.

```
>>> "a string".__class__
<class 'str'>
>>> type("a string")
<class 'str'>
```

Note:

```
>>> type(type) is type
True
```

You might also find this form useful if you ever wanted access to the type of an object itself for other reasons.

In its three-argument form, `type(name, bases, namespace)`  it returns *a new type object, a new class*. Just like any other type constructor, just like `list()` returns a new list.

So instead of:

```
class Foo:
    bar = 42
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

You could write:

```
def _foo_init(self, val):
    self.val = val

Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {'bar':42, '__init__': _foo_init})
```

`isinstance` is a function which checks if... an object is an instance of some type. It is a function used for introspection.

When you want to introspect on the type of an object, usually you will probably use `isintance(some_object, SomeType)`, but you might also use `type(some_object) is SomeType`. The key difference is that `isinstance` will return `True` if `some_object.__class__` is *precisely* `SomeType` **or** any of the other types `SomeType` inherits from (i.e. in the method resolution order of `SomeType`, `SomeType.mro()`).

So, `isinstance(some_object, SomeType)` is essentially equivalent to `some_object.__class__ is SomeType or some_object.__class__ in SomeType.mro()`

Whereas if you use `type(some_object) is SomeType`, you are only asking `some_object.__class__ is SomeType`.

Here's a practical example of when you might want to use `type` instead of `isinstance`, suppose you wanted to distinguish between `int` and `bool` objects. In Python, `bool` inherits from `int`, so:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

So that means:

```
>>> some_boolean = True
>>> isinstance(some_boolean, int)
True
```

but

```
>>> type(some_boolean) is int
False
```

Answer (score 1):

type says the type of variable:

```
a = 10
type(a)
```

It will give its type as 'int'

isinstance() says if variable is related to specified type

```
class b:
def __init__(self):
    print('Hi')

c = b()

m = isinstance(c, b)
```

It will return True because object c is of class type a otherwise it will return False.